# How can I redefine the \verb|...| command?

Tags: macros, color, verbatim

I'd like to redefine the `\verb|...|` command so that it had a light-gray background and a little bit darker border around it, and a little bit of padding to make this background "box" noticable. Anyone knows how to do that? If that is not possible to do easily, can I define a new command that acts like `\verb|...|` and does that?

Comment: Note that it is `\verb<char>...<char>`, e.g. `\verb|...|` or `\verb{...{`, not `\verb{..}`.

Comment: It's a pitty that `xparse` doesn't support a verbatim argument type.

Comment: @Martin: There are good reasons why `xparse` does not deal with verbatim material (essentially, a truly general solution is not available, as TeX's parsing approach makes certain cases impossible to handle with generalised code).

Comment: @Joseph: Indeed. I just had a look on `\verb` again to improve `newverbs` and will have to at least provide two ways: one which really only provides the verbatim characters and one which provides them in a typeset-able form (e.g. using `\@noligs`).

Comment: Preview on new version of `newverbs` ([already implemented in the develop version](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/general/browser/newverbs/dev)): `\newcommand\myverb{\collectverbtext{\@myverb}}` `\def\@myverb#1{The collected verb text: "#1"}`

Answer (score 12):

#### Update 2011-07-27

As promised the new version of my `newverbs` package provides two macros to collect verbatim arguments with the `\verb|...|` syntax but also with `{ .. }`.
For typesettable verbatim use `\collectverb{\macrowhichgetsitasargument}`.

For the requested colored background and frame use the `\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{<text>}` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/23]
\newcommand{\myverb}{\collectverb{\fcolorbox{black!50}{black!25}}}

\begin{document}
    \myverb|%^&\|
    \myverb{%^&\}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

The `newverbs` package allows you to define variations of the `\verb` command which code placed before and after it. You need to use a savebox for advanced formatting. (I'm planning to also support macros which receive the verbatim text as normal argument in the next version.)

Example:

```
\usepackage{newverbs}

\newverbcommand{\myverb}{\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}\mytextformatmacro}{\end{lrbox}{\mycommand{\usebox{\verbbox}}}

...

\myverb|%^&\|
```

Use the `xcolor` package to add colors.

The package already provides `\fverb` (draws a `\fbox` around it) and `\qverb` (adds quoting signs) by default.

You could also use the `\verb`-like `\lstinline` macro of the `listings` package. It accepts the many `listings` options.

Comment: `\lstinline` does not support `backgroundcolor`, at least in my version, which is pretty sad. By not supporting I mean not an error, but lack of the effect.

Comment: @przemoc: If you want `backgroundcolor` with `\lstinline`, perhaps [how to redefine lstinline to automatically highlight or draw frames around all inline code snippets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30845/how-to-redefine-lstinline-to-automatically-highlight-or-draw-frames-around-all/30851#30851) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've modified the standard `\verb` command and got the result, but anyway I recommend Martin's approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{cverbbackground}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{cverbborder}{gray}{0.2}
\makeatletter
\newbox\cverbbox
\def\cverb{\setbox\cverbbox=\hbox\bgroup
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@ifstar\@scverb\@cverb}
\def\@scverb#1{%
  \catcode`#1\active
  \lccode`\~`#1%
  \gdef\verb@balance@group{\cverb@egroup
     \@latex@error{\noexpand\verb illegal in command argument}\@ehc}%
  \aftergroup\verb@balance@group
  \lowercase{\let~\cverb@egroup}}%
\def\@cverb{\@vobeyspaces \frenchspacing \@scverb}
\def\cverb@egroup{\global\let\verb@balance@group\@empty\egroup
  \fcolorbox{cverbborder}{cverbbackground}{\box\cverbbox}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cverb|ab{\c| \cverb*|a }|
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's basically what `newverbs` does by itself, except it adds small begin and end hooks in the normal `\verb` so that it can be reused for multiple `\verb` like macros. It also support the `\verb` replacement of `tabularx` as a bonus.

Comment: @Martin: I supposed so. It was just to try it out.

Comment: This solution is the best i ve found, but is there a way to change `\verb{}` font color, and font size?

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution which works with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Fverb}{v}
      {\fcolorbox{black!50}{black!25}{#1}}
\begin{document} 
HALLO \Fverb|\foo| HALLO
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite: ``\Fverb|!`|`` will give `¡`.

Comment: @egreg: Why this? I tested only commands ;-). A space between `|! \`|` works.

Comment: The font has ligatures defined. Indeed in traditional verbatim mode the backquote, `<`, `>` and `-` are active and defined so as not to produce ligatures.