# Is it possible to embed source code in a regular text with "listings"?

Tags: listings

I want to write something like

```
In order to avoid a RuntimeException
```

where `RuntimeException` appears with a code font.

I've tried something like

```
\begin{lstlisting} In order to avoid a RuntimeException \end{lstlisting}
```

but it was of no avail. Any suggestions? If it isn't possible, could anyone point out what's the font being used by default by `listings`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

Use `\lstinline` for inline listings:

[image]

The `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}` is for displayed listings.

### References:

- If you are interested in highlighting inline listsings, see [How to redefine \lstinline to automatically highlight or draw frames around all inline code snippets?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30845/how-to-redefine-lstinline-to-automatically-highlight-or-draw-frames-around-all/30851#30851).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}
\begin{document}
    To avoid a  \lstinline´RuntimeException´ you need to...
\end{document}
```