# Making Inline Code Printing Pretty

Tags: listings, color, boxes, inline

I have to include small code snippets like method and class names within continuous text.
I do not want to display those snippets as complete seperated listings, they should be displayed inline, similar to the option this site offers with `backticks`.

But let's face it, the options that are available out of the box are just plain ugly.

What I have in mind is the notation GitHub (and many other sites) use:

[image]

So, in particular:

- rounded corners
- contrastring border color
- different background color
- fixed width code font
- pretty (vertical) alignment within the text

I found many options to draw boxes around text (`fancybox`, `colorbox`, `mdframed` and others)
but none of those packages seemed to be capable to fulfill all of my requirements (then again, I'm not really a LaTeX expert).

So the question is: How can we make inline code pretty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\code[1]{
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[rounded corners,fill=orange!20,draw=gray]{\texttt{#1}};
  }
}

\begin{document}

Further, lists can be turned into \textcolor{blue}{Task Lists} 
by prefacing list items with \code{[ ]} or \code{[x]} (incomplete or complete,
respectively.

\end{document}
```

---

### Update

A slight improvement of the `\code` macro, to ensure uniform height and depth of the box regardless of the height/depth of its content. Also, the improved macro `\codex` admits an optional argument.

```
\newcommand\codex[2][]{
    \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
        \node(s)[
            rounded corners,
            fill=blue!5,        % background color
            draw=gray,          % border of box
            text=gray!50!black, % text color
            inner xsep =3pt,    % horizontal space between text and border
            inner ysep =0pt,    % vertical space between text and border
            text height=2ex,    % height of box
            text depth =1ex,    % depth of box
            #1                  % other options
        ]{\texttt{#2}};
    }
}
```

Compare the output of `\code` and the improved version `\codex`

```
\code{aaaa} \code{bbbb} \code{ffff} \code{gggg} \code{<code>\textbackslash code</code>}

\codex{aaaa} \codex{bbbb} \codex{ffff} \codex{gggg} \codex{<code>\textbackslash code</code>}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks very promising :) , what is missing is a (thin) border around the box

Comment: @Mef: see updated answer. The box can be drawn by adding `draw=<color>` option to the `node` operation.

Comment: Nice work! One more thing to make it perfect: Can the text color also be changed within this command (dark grey instead of black)?

Comment: @Mef Add `text=gray!50!black` into the option of the `\node`.

Comment: @Mef: I've made a slight improvement of the macro to ensure uniform height and depth of the box despite its content. See update in the answer.

Comment: Is there a nice way to accomplish this by using the `listings` package? The manual said one should not use `listings` inside arguments, so creating a custom macro as you did seems not to be the best option...?

Comment: I guess, I will have to use something like you provided, since `\lstinline` definitely does not support frames or background color...

Comment: @LCsa: I'm not familiar enough with the `listings` package to answer your question. You may want to consider opening a post for this question. I'm sure someone on TeX.SX will be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I maybe open a new question, but before I'll work around a bit by myself. Thanks, I just thought, it could be interesting in the light of this question. cheers.

Comment: There seems to be a solution for [lstinline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30845/14593) now.