# Can the command \minted and \mintinline have rounded corners without depending on the package listings? Are tcolorbox and tikz needed?

Tags: xetex, listings, tikz-styles, minted, rounded-corners

I use XeLaTeX, but I can not use both or similar or duplicate packages, because someone said it is bad idea in XeLaTeX. I would like to use only minted.

Here are two answers which offer inline code with rounded corners, but only for `lstinline` and `minted`:

- [How do I set a background color and font for inline verb text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452249/how-do-i-set-a-background-color-and-font-for-inline-verb-text)
- [Advanced customization of Minted code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452150/advanced-customization-of-minted-code?answertab=active#tab-top)

But in these links, both they depend on `listings`.

Few codes taken from the one of two links and I readjusted few commands and words, as principally replacing `listing`. for `minted` and `\lstinline`. for `\mintline`, without depending on `listings`, but it does not work without `listings`. Here is the smaller code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, portuguese]{abntex2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted, skins, xparse}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{2mm}\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=bg, colframe=bg, arc=1.2pt]}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}\vspace{2mm}}%

\usepackage{newverbs}
\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}{\color{inline}}{}
\usemintedstyle{paraiso-dark}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\commandbox}{ s v }
{minted, enhanced, frame hidden, arc=2pt}
{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textcolor{red}{\ttfamily\bfseries > }}{}%
\mintinline{#1}{#2}^#3^}

\begin{document} 

\commandbox{php}{<?php echo "Hello!" ?>}

\end{document}
```

And without depending on `listings` and with `tikz` from [Making Inline Code Printing Pretty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140166/making-inline-code-printing-pretty?rq=1), I only replaced `{\texttt{#2}}` for `{\mintinline{#1}{#2}}`, but I tested and it did not work error:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, portuguese]{abntex2}

%...

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[2]
{
    \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]
    {
        \node(s)
        [
            rounded corners,
            fill = whitesmoke, % background color
            % draw = prussianblue,    % border of box
            text = solitudeblue,  % text color
            inner xsep = 2pt,    % horizontal space between text and border
            inner ysep = 0pt,    % vertical space between text and border
            text height = 2ex,    % height of box
            text depth = 1ex,    % depth of box
            #1                  % other options
        ]{\mintinline{#1}{#2}};
    }
}

\begin{document} 

The basic code in PHP \inlinecode{php}{<?php echo "Hello $name" ?>}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The code in the second link (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452150/35864) still works fine if all references to `listings` are removed.

Comment: BTW: It is *always* bad to load packages twice or to load packages you don't need or don't know what they are doing (not only with XeLaTeX). It is also always a good idea to try and reduce the number of packages loaded: `minted` and `listings` do very similar things, so it seems not too far-fetched that it should be possibly to use only one of the two. AFAIK `minted` and `listings` are not incompatible, so it is not bad to use both, but it is nicer to get away with using only one of the two.

Comment: Check what one package does. Check what the other package does. Check that against what you want to do. Tell us what you want to do so we don't just guess. Also make a MWE so we don't have to guess some more.

Comment: @Joseph, ready, I have just updated the detail.

Comment: @GustavoReis, it's not a MWE -- see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. In the links you took that code from you have examples of MWE (which work). What do you want that is different from them?

Comment: Ready, @Joseph. Improved?

Comment: @GustavoReis It is still not a MWE. Have you looked the link provided by Joseph? A MWE should be a short compilable code that reproduces the issue, thus, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have just updated the text, the explications and the code sources. Is it still MWE? I have read MWE several times and tried to improve the detail.