# Adding a highlight to \texttt blocks

Tags: color, highlighting, typewriter

I'm trying the add a grey highlight to the `\texttt` command to essentially achieve the same effect as the `code blocks on here.`

This is something I attempted to do when I first started writing my current document. I don't remember how I got there but the renew command I wrote looks like this:

```
\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.90}
\sethlcolor{Light}

\renewcommand{\texttt}{\hl}
```

This gives me the grey highlight, but the font it no longer monospace.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22417/4427) for verbatim mode, but it could be what you want

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make a small tweak:

```
\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\OldTexttt{\hl{#1}}}
```

to get `normal text \texttt{foo bar} normal text` to yield:

[image]

### Alternative Solution:

Note that the above solution will effect **all** uses of `\texttt{}`.
If that is not desired, an alternative solution would be to define a custom macro:

```
\newcommand{\hltexttt}[1]{\texttt{\hl{#1}}}
```

and then use `\hltexttt{}` when you want both the `\hl` and `\texttt` effect.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.90}
\sethlcolor{Light}

\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\OldTexttt{\hl{#1}}}% will affect all \texttt
%\newcommand{\hltexttt}[1]{\texttt{\hl{#1}}}% comment above \renewcommand if want this

\begin{document}
normal text \texttt{foo bar} normal text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the alternative better than the main solution.

Comment: Please, what would be the modification in a Beamer document .

Comment: @robintux: AFAIK, this should work in Beamer. If not, please ask a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: @robintux [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75120/2100) have some alternatives to using highlight in beamer, although [scavi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691310/2100) is probably even better.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Grill already provided a [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42964/164255). Just as an alternative, you can also achieve this using `\colorbox` or `\fcolorbox`. The letter additionally allows you to specify a border color:

[image]

#### Code:

```latex
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codebg}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{codeframe}{gray}{0.8}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\fcolorbox{codeframe}{codebg}{\small\!\texttt{#1}\!}}
```

```
normal text \inlinecode{foo bar} normal text
```