# How to make highlighting work in beamer with overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays, soul

I'm trying to use the soul package to get highlighting via `\hl{some text}`.  I'd like to do this in overlays in beamer.  I'm trying to follow the guidelines in section 9.6.1 of the beamer manual to make the `\hl` command overlay aware.  What i'm using is

`\renewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}}{#1}}`

That setup sorta/kinda works, but not exactly.

- The `\hl` command is overlay-aware in xelatex, but not in pdflatex or lualatex.  I generally use lualatex, so that would be my preference. ([Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301) has addressed this part in the first half of his answer)
- The overlays tend to reflow the text a bit, in a way that makes the highlighted text jump around from slide to slide in an awkward manner.  You'll see that if you run the example below through xelatex. (Actually, you'll see it in all the engines, but only with the highlights in xelatex). (Peter addressed this in the TikZ part of his answer)

I've attached an MWE of the problem, which I'm sure is some simple ignorance on my part, but I can't seem to resolve.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{.90,.95,1}
\sethlcolor{lightblue}
\renewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} {Some possibly highlighted text}

This is some normal text

\hl<2>{I'd like this text to appear on both slides, but only be
  highlighted from the second slide}

\hl<3>{I'd like this text to appear on both slides, but only be
  highlighted from the second slide.  This is a long one, so it should
be more than one line}

This is some normal text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  What is `#2` in the `\renewcommand`? `\hl` only takes on parameter? Oh, wait perhaps this is one of those `beamer` things I don't know about.

Comment: The #2 is the argument to specify the overlay, like <2> to specify the second slide, or <2-> to specify from the second slide until the end of the frame.  The overlay-aware versions of commands in beamer can take such an extra argument

Comment: Yep, realized it was something like that once I saw the `<>` syntax.  Don't really have much experience with `beamer` so thanks for teaching me something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Using `soul` package:

Looks like the problem is that `beamer` redefines things.  Using the patch from [Why is it that coloring in soul in beamer is not visible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41683/why-is-it-that-coloring-in-soul-in-beamer-is-not-visible) seems to work:

[image]

### Using `tikz` package:

As Andrew Stacey mentioned int he comments, there is a `tikzmark` solution as well. Using the code from [How to "highlight" text/formulas with tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/how-to-highlight-text-formals-with-tikz), we get:

[image]

### Notes:

- Using this solution, the text is identical across the frames.
- This required a slight tweak from the code at [How to "highlight" text/formulas with tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/how-to-highlight-text-formals-with-tikz).  The `highlighter width` was increased form `12pt`:

  ```
    highlighter width/.initial=14pt
  ```

  Without this there was additional spacing in between the highlighted lines of the second paragraph.
- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Further Enhancements:

- Another thing to look into would be adapting solutions from [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex).

---

### Code (`soul`):

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{.90,.95,1}
\sethlcolor{lightblue}
\renewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}}{#1}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41683/why-is-it-that-coloring-in-soul-in-beamer-is-not-visible
\makeatletter
\newcommand\SoulColor{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color}
\makeatother
\SoulColor

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} {Some possibly highlighted text}

This is some normal text

\hl<2>{I'd like this text to appear on both slides, but only be
  highlighted from the second slide}

\hl<3>{I'd like this text to appear on both slides, but only be
  highlighted from the second slide.  This is a long one, so it should
be more than one line}

This is some normal text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code (`tikz`):

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/how-to-highlight-text-formals-with-tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
%
% Highlighter code
%

\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
    \pgfpointorigin
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}

\newcounter{highlight}
\newcommand{\hlstart}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlstart\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\hl@start}
\newcommand{\hlend}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlend\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\hl@end\stepcounter{highlight}}
\newcommand{\fdstart}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlstart\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\fd@start}
\newcommand{\fdend}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlend\the\value{highlight},baseline=-0.7ex];\fd@end\stepcounter{highlight}}
\newcommand{\vlstart}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlstart\the\value{highlight},baseline=-1em];\vl@start}
\newcommand{\vlend}{\tikz[remember picture with id=hlend\the\value{highlight},baseline=0.3ex];\vl@end\stepcounter{highlight}}

\newcommand{\hl@start}[1][]{%
  \hl@draw{highlighter}{#1}{\the\value{highlight}}}

\newcommand{\hl@end}{}

\newcommand{\fd@start}[1][]{%
  \def\fd@args{#1}}

\newcommand{\fd@end}{\def\@tempa{\hl@draw{fader}}\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\fd@args}{\the\value{highlight}}\def\fd@args{}}

\newcommand{\vl@start}[1][]{%
  \vl@draw{highlighter}{#1}{\the\value{highlight}}}

\newcommand{\vl@end}{}


\def\hl@sets{%
  \edef\hl@sx{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef\hl@sy{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\def\hl@sete{%
  \edef\hl@ex{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef\hl@ey{\the\pgf@y}%
}

\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{

\def\page@node{
  \path (current page.south east)
      ++(-\beamer@rightmargin,\footheight)
  node[
    minimum width=\textwidth,
    minimum height=\textheight,
    anchor=south east
  ] (page) {};
}

}{

  \def\page@node{
    \path (current page.north west)
    ++(\hoffset + 1in + \oddsidemargin + \leftskip,\voffset + 1in + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep)
    node[
      minimum width=\textwidth - \leftskip - \rightskip,
      minimum height=\textheight,
      anchor=north west
    ] (page) {};
  }

}

\newcommand{\hl@draw}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \page@node
  \tikzset{#2,highlight=#1,every path/.append style={highlight=#1}}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@width}{\the\pgflinewidth - 1pt}%
  \coordinate (hlstart) at (pic cs:hlstart#3);
  \coordinate (hlend) at (pic cs:hlend#3);
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sets(pic cs:hlstart#3)
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sete(pic cs:hlend#3)
  \ifdim\hl@sy=\hl@ey\relax
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlend);
  \else
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlstart -| page.east);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sy}{\hl@sy -\hl@width}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@ey}{\hl@ey +\hl@width}%
  \loop\ifdim\hl@sy>\hl@ey\relax
  \draw (0,\hl@sy -| page.west) -- (0,\hl@sy -| page.east);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sy}{\hl@sy -\hl@width}%
  \repeat
  \draw (hlend -| page.west) -- (hlend);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\vl@draw}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \page@node
  \tikzset{#2,highlight=#1,every path/.append style={highlight=#1}}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@width}{\the\pgflinewidth - 1pt}%
  \coordinate (hlstart) at (pic cs:hlstart#3);
  \coordinate (hlend) at (pic cs:hlend#3);
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sets(pic cs:hlstart#3)
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hl@sete(pic cs:hlend#3)
  \ifdim\hl@sx=\hl@ex\relax
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlend);
  \else
  \draw (hlstart) -- (hlstart |- page.south);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sx}{\hl@sx -\hl@width}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@ex}{\hl@ex +\hl@width}%
  \loop\ifdim\hl@sx>\hl@ex\relax
  \draw (\hl@sx,0 |- page.north) -- (\hl@sx,0 |- page.south);
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\hl@sx}{\hl@sx -\hl@width}%
  \repeat
  \draw (hlend |- page.north) -- (hlend);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\tikzset{%
  highlight/.default=highlighter,
  highlight/.style={
    color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 colour},
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 width},
    line cap=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 cap},
    opacity=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1 opacity},
  },
  highlighter colour/.initial=yellow,
  highlighter width/.initial=14pt,% <-- Tweak (was 12pt)
  highlighter cap/.initial=butt,
  highlighter opacity/.initial=1,
  fader colour/.initial=gray,
  fader width/.initial=12pt,
  fader cap/.initial=butt,
  fader opacity/.initial=.5,
}



\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{

%% Beamer variants

\setbeamercolor{highlighted text}{bg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{faded text}{fg=gray}

\newcommand<>{\highlight}[2][]{%
  \only#3{\hlstart[#1]}#2\only#3{\hlend}}

\newcommand<>{\fade}[2][]{%
  \only#3{\fdstart[#1]}#2\only#3{\fdend}}

\newcommand<>{\vhighlight}[2][]{%
  \only#3{\vlstart[#1]}#2\only#3{\vlend}}

}{

\newcommand{\highlight}[2][]{%
\hlstart[#1]#2\hlend}

\newcommand{\fade}[2][]{%
\fdstart[#1]#2\fdend}

\newcommand{\vhighlight}[2][]{%
\vlstart[#1]#2\vlend}

}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame} {Some possibly highlighted text}

This is some normal text

\highlight<2>{I'd like this text to appear on both slides, but only be
  highlighted from the second slide}

\highlight<3>{I'd like this text to appear on both slides, but only be
  highlighted from the second slide.  This is a long one, so it should
be more than one line}

This is some normal text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter, that solves the problem of using pdflatex or lualatex. Thanks!  Now just left with the problem of changes in text layout through the overlays.

Comment: Sorry to have put you back to _real_ work again. :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting the output as well.  You can see (between slides 2 and 3) the reformatting that gets dragged along with the highlight overlay, at least the way I've done the `\renewcommand` for `\hl`.  The line third from the bottom ends "should be more" in one slide and "should be more than" when highlighted.

Comment: @GTK: Hmmm... I am not sure what is the cause of that.

Comment: What no tikzmark?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: :-) Not sure how to make that work with `beamer`.

Comment: You mean that there's a use of the tikzmark that you don't know!?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46471/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Did know about it but did not occur to me, guess that is because I do not have much experience with `beamer`.  Any idea as to why the highlighting is off for the second paragraph?

Comment: @PeterGrill Off in what way?  Do you mean the spacing?  That's because the highlighter works by "dragging" a highlighter across the page so the thickness might need adjusting.  Try adding a small amount to the highlighter thickness.

Comment: @AndrewStacey; Thanks. Increasing the `highlighter width` from `12pt` to `14pt` seems to have fixed it. But if you increase it to `15pt`, "strange" things happen: only every second line is highlighted.  Logically, I think I know why what that is occurring, but don't know this code well enough to try to address it.

Comment: The `soul` solution reintroduces the [overlay position jump problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer) for some reason. The `tikz` solution works great.