# Why does a dash ('-') in \texttt{} cause the last character not to be rendered?

Tags: typewriter

I have modified the `\texttt{}` command based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42964/99537) answer to give the rendered text a highlight:

```
\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\OldTexttt{\hl{#1}}}
```

I am not experienced in TeX, so I don't really know what the command does and what side effects it has. All I know is that it has added the highlight. There are obviously some problems because a rendered text with a dash in it is missing its last character.

Source code (minimal working example /as requested/):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{fithesis2}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\sethlcolor{gray}

\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\OldTexttt{\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\texttt{game-server.js}

\end{document}
```

If needed, `fithesis2` is downloadable from the [website of our university](https://www.fi.muni.cz/tech/unix/tex/fithesis.xhtml.cs) by clicking on [Soubory třídy fithesis2 jako ZIP, cca 880 KiB](https://www.fi.muni.cz/lemma/projekty/download/fithesis2-current.zip).

Compiled PDF:

[image: Compiled PDF]

I have tried to remove the `\texttt{}` modification and it fixed the problem with the missing character, but I would actually like to keep the highlight. Removing `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` also helps but I guess I need that line because I'm writing in Czech. (?)

Removing the `\texttt{}` modification also breaks line-breaking which now doesn't happen inside the text rendered by `\texttt{}` at all, so now I'm left with some lines going over the right edge.

How to do it so that I can have all of it - the highlight, working line-breaking and dashes possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us the preamble you're using? Even better, could you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You obviously redefined \texttt (or it wouldn't have such a gray background). So only you can know why it behaves so curiously.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You're right. I have modified the question accordingly. Thank you for reading it again.

Comment: @Zabri Please, add an example of the code you're using.

Comment: @egreg: Done...

Comment: You would make it so much easier to help you if you'd (1) take your code (2) boil it down to a few lines of code that still show that behavior (minimal working example) (3) and post those lines here (not as a picture, but as text). This way people could try and help you solve the issue. With what you are giving them here, they can only guess

Comment: I have modified the question and added a MWE.

Comment: Now it's much clearer: it seems an incompatibility of `soul` with `babel-czech`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an incompatibility between `soul` and `babel-czech` (and `babel-slovak` as well). When doing its working, `soul` looks for a standard `-` and it doesn't find it even if it appears to be there, because `babel-czech` changes the hyphen into an active character.

Thus the problem appears only when a hyphen is found in the argument to `\hl`, because the character count is off by one.

Here's a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd*{\SOUL@eval}{\cO\-}{\cA\-}{}{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\sethlcolor{gray}

\begin{document}

\hl{abc-def}

\hl{abcdef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's it for your minimal example; note the small changes I made, notably the usage of `utf8` instead of `utf8x`, `soulutf8` instead of `soul` and a better redefinition of `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{fithesis2}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd*{\SOUL@eval}{\cO\-}{\cA\-}{}{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\sethlcolor{gray}

\LetLtxMacro\OldTexttt\texttt
\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{\OldTexttt{\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\hl{game-server.js}

\texttt{game-server.js}

\end{document}
```

[image]