# Highlight \verb in inline text

Tags: verbatim, highlighting, backgrounds

I'm new in LaTeX and I'm searching for solution to highlight verbatim text inside paragraph (for example, it is like on this page, where code is highlighted). Can anyone help me with this?

Let say, that I have a paragraph and inside is some words where I use `\verb||` to show some code parts, but I'd like that this is highlighted or it has background color, juts like it is highlighted in this page. For normal text I can use `\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{gray!10}{some text}}`, but this command doesn't work with `\verb`, so I can't use it. I'm trying to find solution and searching over the internet, but I didn't fid so far.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know the package `newverbs`? See, for instance, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22416/how-can-i-redefine-the-verb-command and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114997/how-do-i-define-a-custom-verbatim-command

Comment: I didn't know for this package. Will read this posts and test, if it will work well for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}{\color{red}}{}

\begin{document}
Text \cverb|&*}| and more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Version with a macro for having a background text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\newverbcommand{\cverb}{\color{red}}{}
\newverbcommand{\bverb}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}}
  {\end{lrbox}\colorbox{gray!30}{\box\verbbox}}

\begin{document}
Text \cverb|&*}| and more text

Text \bverb|&*}| and more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good for changing color. How do I change background color (grey)?

Comment: @Phantom Added new macro

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
This is a
\color{red}
\begin{verbbox}
\verbatim text
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
\color{black}
~that is inline

\end{document}
```

[image]