# Format Inline source code like Stack Exchange

Tags: formatting, sourcecode

Stack Exchange formats code nicely with backticks using Markdown.

Example: `int foo = bar++`

I've seen other posts that recommend using listings, specifically `\lstinline` to do inline source code.

Using `listings` or any other packages, how could the Stack Exchange code formatting be emulated in LaTeX?

Comment: Do you mean with a monospaced font and a grey background?

Comment: `yes, i guess that is all it really is` <- like this

Comment: Ok, then I think your question is a duplicate of [Highlight \verb in inline text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120966).