# Escaping "math" characters in boxed verb

Tags: verbatim

When I want to print out some common "special meaning" characters, I use the `\verb` command, i.e.

```
\verb?x^2 + 1?
```

(No, I **don't** wan't to use the math mode, I want to print out that `^` character.)

Works fine, except then when I want to "box" the text. This: `\fbox{\verb?x + 1?}` works fine, but this: `\fbox{\verb?x^2 + 1?}` fails: seems that the fbox removes the verbatim-ness, and processes the `^` as math-mode (even though I didn't put any `$`...)

Question: is there a "simple" way to (re-)enable the verbatim mode inside a `\fbox` ?

Note: I also checked [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22416/), however I am unable to make [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22417/11083) work.

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```
\texttt{x\char`\^2 + 1}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Seems to be the simplest (no additional package). And, for the record, `\fbox{\texttt{x\char`\^2 + 1}}` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `verbatimbox` package can help.  It also works on true `verbatim`, unlike a `\texttt` alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\verb?x^2 + 1 + \alpha? \par
\begin{verbbox}x^2 + 1 + \alpha\end{verbbox}
\fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]